# innerHTML flash video not loading problem

Tags: javascript, flash, variables, parameters, onclick

when the "preview" link is clicked it is meant to change the video script and video swf using the innerHTML method, however in IE 7+ the flash seems to appear but never loads the video i.e. it just stays white.

```
<script>
function changeVideo(filename,script) {document.getElementById('video').innerHTML =
'<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0"
width="610" height="400" id="movie" align=""><param name="'+filename+'"
value="'+filename+'.swf"><embed src="'+filename+'.swf" quality="high" width="610"
height="400" name="'+filename+'" align="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" plug
inspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">';
document.getElementById('mainText').innerHTML = script;
}
</script>

--//--

 <div id="video">

 </div>

 <div id="mainText">
 <p style="margin-top:0px;">Some Text</p>
 </div>

 <div id="videoSelector">
    <div class="videoPolaroid">
       <div class="videoThumb"><img src="images/preview-image.jpg" /></div>
       <div class="videoCaption">Caption</div>
       <div class="videoPreview"><a href="#" onclick="changeVideo('robots','<p><b>Some more text<\/b><\/p>'); return false;">Preview</a></div>
       <div class="videoDownload"><a href="#">Download</a></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I intended for the javascript to take 2 parameters, the video file name and the HTML text that's to be placed in the "mainText" div.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You might consider using SWFObject instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) in this case you can use the function

```
function changeVideo(filename,script){
    swfobject.embedSWF(filename, "video", "610", "400", "9.0.0");
    document.getElementById('mainText').innerHTML = script;
}
```

Remember to include swfojbect javascript file in your page. You can fetch the file from Google's CDN [check here](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#swfobject)

Comment: I didn't know the swfobject was so simple to use. :) I'll give that a go, thanks.

Comment: I used the function above and included the swfobject.js file but now it's not working at all, in any browsers. If I click the Preview link, it changes the text in the "mainText" div but changed the video but stays white because it's not loading. Any suggestions?